# Are Activemq, Redis and Apache camel a right combination?

Tags: apache, redis, activemq-classic

Are Activemq, Redis and Apache camel a right combination?

Am planning for a high performant enterprise level integration solution accross multiple applications

My objective is to make the solution
a. independent of the consumers performance
b. able to trouble shoot in case of any issue
c. highly available with failover support
d. Hanlde 10k msgs per second

Here I'm planning to have 
a. network of activemq brokers running in all app servers and storing the consumed messages in redis data store
b. from redis data store, application can retrieve the messages through camel end points
(camel end point is chosen to process the messages before reaching the app).

Also can ActiveMQ be removed with only Redis + Apache camel, as I see from the discussions forms that Redis does most of the ActiveMQ stuff

Could any one advise on this technology stack.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ and Camel works great together and scales very well - should be no problem to handle the load given proper hardware.

Are you thinking about something like this?

```
Message producer App -> ActiveMQ -> Camel -> Redis

Message Consumer App <- Camel [some endpoint] <- Redis
```

Puting ActiveMQ in between is usually a very good way to achieve HA, load balancing and making the solution elastic. Depending on your specific setup with machines etc. ActiveMQ can help in many ways to solve HA issues.

Removing ActiveMQ can a good option if your apps use some other protocol than JMS/ActiveMQ messaging, i.e. HTTP, raw tcp or similar. Can you elaborate on how the apps will communicate with Camel? ActiveMQ, by default, supports transactions, guaranteed delivery and you can live with a limited number of threads on the server, even for your heavy traffic. For other protocols, this might be a bit trickier to achieve. Without a HA layer (cluster) in ActiveMQ you need to setup Redis to handle HA in all aspects, which might be just as easy, but Redis is a bit memory hungry, so be aware of that.

Comment: Hi Petter,
Thanks for the insight on Redis.
Actually I'm thinking of 
Message Prodcer App -> Redis -> Camel -> ActiveMQ
Message Consumer App <- Redis <- Camel <- ActiveMQ
Apps are of different nature and hence thought of bringing Redis close to App which may reduce compatibility issues.
Also I'm planning to bundle camel functionality with ActiveMQ and not with App(thanks for ActiveMQ's embedded support for Camel)